# Determine if JBoss AS is functional

Tags: jboss, solaris, jboss5.x

To check that JBoss Application Server is running I use a simple grep:

```
ps -ef | grep java | grep -v grep | grep "program.name=run.sh" > /dev/null
```

However while this may prove that it is running, it does not prove that it is functional.  Is there a simple manual command or simililar that can be used to bounce a request and query the result, which would be a more robust solution than just checking the presence of JBoss AS.

Comment: Depends on how you define 'functional'. Having CPU activity? Listening on some ports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For JBoss AS 5 try using [bin\twiddle](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/Twiddle) to check JMX from command line.

Some [twiddle usage examples](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-application-server/305-twiddle-reference.html).

Comment: Brilliant exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a specific version of the Application Server in mind? For AS7, you have a few options:

### Management Console

You can point a browser to your console ports, and attempt to launch the Management Console. The default URL is http://localhost:8080/.

```
[user@host JBOSS_HOME]$ firefox http://localhost:8080/
```

### Management CLI

You could also use the Management CLI, as you can string operation commands to the CLI runtime, where the following example could boot the resource, attempt to connect to it, and then exit.

If the server is running, this would look like:

```
[user@host JBOSS_HOME]$ ./bin/jboss-admin.sh --connect exit
Connected to standalone controller at localhost:9999
[user@host JBOSS_HOME]$
```

It the server isn't running, this would look like:

```
[user@host JBOSS_HOME]$ ./bin/jboss-admin.sh --connect exit
The controller is not available at localhost:9999
[user@host JBOSS_HOME]$
```

### Using jconsole

Assuming that you want something from the command line that is abstracted from the boot sequence and the Management API, so you could always use **jconsole**. For example:

```
[user@host bin]$ jconsole
```

The console boots up with the options as follows:

[image]

Click connect and you're not only checking the runtime status, but the performance specs as well. Might be a useful option.

[image]